# The size of the flare animated icon is too small

Tags: flutter

I am using flare animation in flutter. I created my own animation on the flare account. 
[Here is the link to my flare file](https://www.2dimensions.com/a/2dpal/files/flare/cool-heart)

Now when I am using this animation in my flutter app the animation icon is too small. I am using the flare animation like below:

```
   Container(
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        child: Center(
          child: FlareActor(
            "flare_animations/heart.flr",
            animation: "go",
          ),
        ),
      )
```

I can see the animation happening but its just too small. Increasing the size of the container and trying different boxfit for the FlareActor didn't help as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating animations in Flare, you need to remember about your **artboard size**. Your FlareActor widget is as big as your whole artboard, because Flare doesn't measure shapes inside your animation.

If you leave it to default (eg. 1024x768 pixels) and your animation inside will be small (e.g. 100x100 pixels), then setting Container to 50x50 will change size of the whole artboard, so your animation will be much smaller (about few pixels).

To fix this, you can either **change artboard size to smaller** (tap on Artboard in the menu on the left, then change Size in the menu on the right) or **change animated shape size to bigger** (tap on your shape in the menu on the left, then change Scale in the menu on the right).

Comment: That totally worked for me. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well I have one more issue. I am using a heart animation. Which when tapped fills the heart. But my heart is already filled when its in the initial state in my app. Initially it should be unfilled as in the animation I created on flare. What am I doing wrong here? Can you please take a look at my flare file?

Comment: Is the heart filled from the beginning or does it fill after you start the app? Basically when you declare FlareActor, your animation starts immediately. If you want your animation to "stay" in some position and to run after you tap, you need to create another animation (next to "go" animation in Flutter project) with unfilled heart. Then, in your Flutter code you need to change between "go" and "idle" animation after tap.

Comment: Yes the heart is filled from the beginning. The animation plays when i tap on the heart which is as expected but its just the initial state. I was expecting since my animation starts from an unfilled state the heart should be unfilled initially. Btw for the condition when I my heart should be unfilled I am not passing any animation to the Flare actor.